# How to check if a condition is present consecutively with Java 8 Streams?

Tags: java

Say I want to return true if given a list of integers (will say employee hours for the day) is greater than 0 6 times in a row. This would mean that the employee has worked at least 6 days in a row. How would I go about implementing this with Java code? I have tried something using the allMatch() stream function but my logic is failing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
List<Integer> x = Arrays.asList(0,0,0,6,0,7,9,0,0,8,9,0,1,0) -> false because there is not a number greater than 0 six times in a row

List<Integer> y = Arrays.asList(0,0,4,7,8,0,9,1,5,7,8,6,4,7) -> true because there is a number greater than 0 six times in a row
```

I have tried something like this but I get confused when capturing the other numbers in the list for comparision.

```
boolean z = y.stream().allMatch(num -> num > 0);
```

Comment: You don't need to use streams for that.

Comment: boolean evenNumber = y.stream().allMatch(n -> n % 2 == 0); getting all even number.

Comment: @RahulRokade that's completely irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 4):

A version using `reduce` might look like

```
Arrays.asList(0,3,...,1,0).stream().reduce(0, 
    (count, number) -> count >= 6 ? count : (number > 0 ? count + 1 : 0)
) >= 6
```

We iterate through the numbers and start with a `count` of 0 - we increment the `count` if the current `number` is larger than 0, otherwise we reset the `count` to 0. If the `count` is already larger than 6 then we do not care anymore about further checking against 0 or incrementing the `count`, this is where a more performant solution should return early.

Comment: It works but it's highly inefficient compared to Stultuske's answer.

Comment: @Olivier maybe, however OP asked for solution using Stream API

Comment: @Olivier and it is not *highly* inefficient. Sure, it does not return early, but it still is O(n).

Comment: You don't really need the `count >= 6` inside the reducer: it doesn't matter if your count exceeds 6, and it doesn't help you to stop early.

Comment: @AndyTurner I do, otherwise I have the same issue as the downvoted deleted answer: it would only count the very last run of non zero numbers. It is not to prevent exceeding the 6, it is to prevent the reset to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should resolve it

```
public static boolean checkConsecutiveDays(int[] row, int cons) {
  int counter = 0;
  for ( int day : row ) {
    if ( day == 0 ) counter = 0; // invalid day? reset
    else counter += 1;
    if ( counter == cons ) return true; // if counter equal to cons -> return true
   }
   return false; // the cons value was never reached
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with something like this:

```java
public static boolean hasConsecutiveDays(List<Integer> hoursList, int consecutiveDays) {
        return IntStream.range(0, hoursList.size() - consecutiveDays + 1)
                .anyMatch(startIndex -> hoursList.subList(startIndex, startIndex + consecutiveDays)
                        .stream()
                        .allMatch(hours -> hours > 0));
```

but it will not be efficient due to creating additional sublists, so If you don’t have to, I would stick to using for loop instead

Answer (score 0):

You can also precompute indices of zeros and check if exists distance greater than 6, assuming sentinel zeros at the beginning and at the end.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> y = Arrays.asList(0,0,4,7,8,0,9,1,5,7,8,6,4,7); //true
        //List<Integer> y = Arrays.asList(0,0,0,6,0,7,9,0,0,8,9,0,1,0); //false
        List<Integer> z = new ArrayList<>(); // indices of zeros and sentinels
        z.add(-1);
        IntStream.range(0, y.size()).filter(i -> y.get(i) == 0).forEach(z::add);
        z.add(y.size());
        System.out.println(z);
        boolean result = IntStream.range(0, z.size() - 1).anyMatch(i -> z.get(i + 1) - z.get(i) > 6);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So there is a way to do this using the Stream API.

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> accumulator = (counter, item) -> {
    if (item > 0) {
        // if the item is greater than 0, the counter is incremented
        return counter + 1;
    } else if (counter >= 6) {
        // since it is not possible to abort the reduce function
        // after six consecutive elements greater than 0 have been found,
        // this extra check is required to store the counter
        return counter;
    } else {
        // otherwise the counter is discarded
        return 0;
    }
};

List<Integer> x = Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 7, 9, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0, 1, 0);
List<Integer> y = Arrays.asList(0, 0, 4, 7, 8, 0, 9, 1, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 7);

int xr = x.stream().reduce(0, accumulator); // 0
int yr = y.stream().reduce(0, accumulator); // 8

print(xr >= 6); // false
print(yr >= 6); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> y = Arrays.asList(0, 0, 4, 7, 8, 0, 9, 1, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 7);
AtomicInteger k = new AtomicInteger();
boolean res = y.stream().anyMatch(g -> {
        if(k.get() == 6){
            return true;
        }
        k.set(g > 0 ? k.get() + 1 : 0);
        return false;
    });
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: why would you need an array for this? if you want to opt for something like this, why not opt for an AtomicInteger or similar?

Comment: ya we can, modified it now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, the code below has a simple, from scratch logic, but it should solve the problem:

````
```
    public static boolean notZero_n_times (List<Integer> l) {

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {

        if (l.get(i) == 0) {
            count = 0;
        } else {
            count ++;
        }

        if (count == 6) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```
````

Comment: A similar answer was already published for this topic. You have to take a look at the others answers before published your.